# Method Overloading With Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I tried to use method overloading in C# WebApi

```
[HttpPost] 
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser(PersonalInfoModel personalInfo){}

[HttpPost] 
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser(RolesModel roles){}
```

On the client I call:
    /UpdateUser(json)
let say we want to update the user personal info, so the json will look like:

```
{firstName: "testUser", lastName: "testUser", age: 20}
```

and it should match the PersonalInfoModel that looks like this:

```
public class PersonalInfoModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

My idea was to update different parts of the user information and to keep
it clear, meaning call the same method with a different object and I thought
UpdateUser on the server will know what function to use and it *failed*
because the server didn't know what route to use.

Next thing I tried to do is to call only One route in the server like this:

```
[HttpPost] 
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser(dynamic obj){
    return Update(obj);
}

public Update(PersonalInfoModel personalInfo){}

public Update(RolesModel roles){}
```

The above also didn't work with the error: 
"The best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments"
I tried to look on google but with no success to overcome this.

Comment: Can you show the request body from client which is calling api.

Comment: Of course @DheerajKumar, I updated the question with this new information

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/[controller]/personalInfo")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser(PersonalInfoModel personalInfo){}

[HttpPost] 
[Route("/api/[controller]/roles")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser(RolesModel roles){}
```

Comment: Welcome @MartinVengai to Stackoverflow. Would you please describe what's different here and why this may work? This increases the quality of your answer significantly and makes it more reasonable to be accepted.

Comment: I tried the above with this error:
'HttpPostAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Route` Attribute to differentiate between these methods for client to call.

```
[Route("api/Update")]
public class UpdateController
{
   [Route("PersonalInfo")]
   [HttpPost] 
   public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser(PersonalInfoModel 
   personalInfo){}

   [Route("Roles")]
   [HttpPost] 
   public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser(RolesModel roles){}
}
```

Then client calls a`pi/Update/PersonalInfo` to call first method and 
`api/Update/Roles` to call second method

Hope this helps.